# Why does my garage door only close if I push it closed?

Tags: garage-door-opener

When I click the button, my garage door always OPENS fine.

However, if I want to close it, hitting the button does not work.  I have to manually shove it open an extra inch (ie, push the garage door in another inch), then, while holding the door open, I click the button, and it closes fine.

What can cause this, and is it an easy fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried adjusting the Open and Close limits.  It worked for a while.  I made it so that the Open Limit was a little more, so that it opened the door all the way.  It worked, but it often made a crunching sound at the end of opening.  Today, it stopped working altogether.

I had two garage door people tell me I needed a new opener.

In the end, I am happy.  It cost me $700, but the new one is so much better.  Quiet and the MyQ app lets me open with my phone, and have Amazon deliver into my garage.  I feel like I was in the stone age before.

Answer (score 4):

1. Find your garage door opener manual (on paper or via the web if you lost your copy.)
2. Perform the entire adjustment sequence from the installation part of the manual - this may be a "limit switch setting" issue, but go through all the checks and adjustments.
3. Perform the post-adjustment safety checks (stop and reverse for a 2x4 laid flat on the floor, stop on beam break, etc.)

If that fixes it, great, it was just out of adjustment. If not, it's possible that its "brain" is scrambled. At which point some of the options are potentially harmful or fatal - the one I had that lost its mind appeared to operate correctly if you didn't look too closely, but it was trying to drive the garage door through the floor on every close. The limit adjustment did not work, and the stop and reverse did not work, which meant that had anyone gotten between the door and the floor without breaking the beam (cat, dog, crawling child) they could have been killed or injured.

That was apparently the result of a lighting strike to a tree about 20 yards away or so. Upon replacement, a surge suppressor was added to the plug for the opener.

Also make sure that the door operates easily and properly disconnected from the opener - that is, by hand, so you know the tracks/springs/etc. are in good order and not having a problem that's masked by the opener.

*I think the stock recommendation is to do the safety checks and manual operation check every 6 months. I know very few people who actually do them that regularly, or at all.*